# How can [this] be undefined in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, this, strict-mode

When I run this code in Chrome, I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

```
function _log()
{
    'use strict'

    [this].concat(Array.from(arguments)).forEach(
        function (obj) { console.log(obj) }
    )
}

_log('foo', 'bar');
```

I don't understand why this is happening. How can `[this]` be undefined? Even if `this` were undefined, `[this]` should still be an array, shouldn't it?

A funny detail is that when I remove the `use strict` line from the function, the error disappears and the code behaves as expected, logging the function context and arguments each on a new line.

Is there maybe something special about using the keyword `this` in strict mode which I'm not aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a fun bug:

You just forgot the semicolon after `'use strict'`, which totally changes how the code is parsed:

```
'use strict'[this].concat...
```

You're taking the property named `"[Object window]"` in the '`use strict`' chain. Of course it's `undefined`, so it doesn't have any property called `"concat"`.

Comment: Didn't you used to have another name?! o_O

Comment: @Liam Are you thinking about "dystroy" ? That was a while ago

Comment: @Lynn You had me scratching my head for a few minutes, there. And I guess I wasn't the only one.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was it. #famousinyourownlifetime :)